# xpages exception calling method NotesXspViewEntry.getDocument()

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a computed column image ( icon ):

```
 <xp:this.iconSrc><![CDATA[#{javascript:var formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");

var iconNumber = parseInt(rowData.getColumnValue("$8"));
if ( formName == "fmCompanie") {

"/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn" + (iconNumber > 99 ? "" : "0") + iconNumber + ".gif"}


else if ( formName == "fmPersContact" )

{  "" }}]]></xp:this.iconSrc>
```

The problem is when I want to open a document listed from my viewPanel, I get the following error: Exception occurred calling method NotesXspViewEntry.getDocument() null

at the following line of code:

```
var formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");
```

Comment: rowData.getDocument() returns null. Probably a category.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth : I tried adding: if (!rowData.isCategory()) { // my code } but still the error exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for `NotesXspViewEntry.getDocument()`

> Returns null if the view entry is not a document. Returns null if the
>   document is deleted after the NotesXspViewEntry (JavaScript) object is
>   created.

I don't think deletion is the problem but it might be a category or total. Check with `isDocument()`

```
if(rowdata.isDocument()) {
  var formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");
  // other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd used if (!rowData.isCategory()) ... too much coffee